# SafeAreaView not filling the phone head area

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing a react native app for iOS.  Included SafeAreaView component with a background color but the top part of the iPhone X is leaving an unfilled space with white background.

I have removed the SafeAreaView and I still see a white area at the top edge that remains unaffected by filling with a background color except when I load a background image. Not sure why the SafeAreaView is not covering the entire SafeArea at the top of the phone; it goes only 50% way.

```
 <Fragment>

      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 0, backgroundColor: '#006600' }}  />
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#006600' }} > 
      <StatusBar barStyle='light-content' />
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header 
          headerText={'My Naija Calculator'} 
          backgroundColor = {'#006600'}
          color = { '#fff'}
          />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using `SafeAreaView` wrong

`SafeAreaView` acts like a `View`. You just need to wrap it once around all the children elements

```
<SafeAreaView>
   <Component1 />
   <Component2 />
</SafeAreaView>
```

reference: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad. I had a padding of 20 stuck in some forgotten bounding view component. I deleted it and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor:'green'}}>
       <Text>hello</Text>
     </SafeAreaView>
```

you can try this